# formatted reading using awk

Tags: scripting, awk, simulation

I am trying to read in a formatted file using awk. The content looks like the following:

```
    1PS1     A1    1  11.197   5.497   7.783
    1PS1     A1    1  11.189   5.846   7.700
    .
    .
    .
```

Following c format, these lines are in following format
"%5d%5s%5s%5d%8.3f%.3f%8.3f"
where, first 5 positions are integer (1), next 5 positions are characters (PS1), next 5 positions are characters (A1), next 5 positions are integer (1), next 24 positions are divided into 3 columns of 8 positions with 3 decimal point floating numbers.

What I've been using is just calling these lines separated by columns using "$1, $2, $3". For example,

```
cat test.gro | awk 'BEGIN{i=0} {MolID[i]=$1; id[i]=$2; num[i]=$3; x[i]=$4; 
y[i]=$5; z[i]=$6; i++} END { ...} >test1.gro
```

But I ran into some problems with this, and now I am trying to read these files in a formatted way as discussed above.

Any idea how I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your sample input, it seems the format string is actually `"%5d%-5s%5s%5d%8.3f%.3f%8.3f"` with the first string field being left-justified. It's too bad awk doesn't have a `scanf()` function, but you can get your data with a few `substr()` calls

```
awk -v OFS=: '
  {
     a=substr($0,1,5)
     b=substr($0,6,5)
     c=substr($0,11,5)
     d=substr($0,16,5)
     e=substr($0,21,8)
     f=substr($0,29,8)
     g=substr($0,37,8)
     print a,b,c,d,e,f,g
   }
'
```

outputs

```
    1:PS1  :   A1:    1:  11.197:   5.497:   7.783
    1:PS1  :   A1:    1:  11.189:   5.846:   7.700
```

If you have GNU awk, you can use the `FIELDWIDTHS` variable like this:

```
gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS="5 5 5 5 8 8 8" -v OFS=: '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7}'
```

also outputs

```
    1:PS1  :   A1:    1:  11.197:   5.497:   7.783
    1:PS1  :   A1:    1:  11.189:   5.846:   7.700
```

Answer (score 2):

You never said exactly which fields you think should have what number, so I'd like to be clear about how `awk` thinks that works (Your choice to be explicit about calling the whitespace in your output format string fields makes me worry a little. You might have a different idea about this than `awk`.).

From the manpage:

> An input line is normally made up of fields separated by  white  space,
>      or by regular expression FS.  The fields are denoted $1, $2, ..., while
>      $0 refers to the entire line.  If FS is null, the input line  is  split
>      into one field per character.

Take note that the whitespace in the input line does not get assigned a field number and that sequential whitespace is treated as a single field separator.

You can test this with something like:

```
echo "1   2 3 4" | awk '{print "1:" $1 "\t2:" $2 "\t3:" $3 "\t4:" $4}'
```

at the command line.

---

All of this assumes that you have not diddles the `FS` variable, of course.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I forgot that I could use FIELDWIDTHS option with gawk.

Comment: @Greg: If it was `FIELDWIDTHS` that solved you problem shouldn't you accept glenn's answer?